# Kubernetes deployment multiple replicas - how to pass replica number to pod

Tags: kubernetes

A new Kubernetes Deployment with 2+ replicas for high availability.

I want to be able to execute a command on the first pod only, let's say create a DB, and let the other replicas wait for the first one to complete.
To implement this, I just want to know in the pod if this is replica #1 or not.

So in the pod's entry point I can test:

```
if [ $REPLICA_ID -eq 1 ]; then 
    CreateDB
else
    WaitForDB
fi
```

Can this be done in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

in Kubernetes a `Deployment` is considered stateless and therefore doesn't provide the feature you're looking for. You should rather look into `StatefulSet` and their features.

A `StatefulSet`e.g. supports [ordered creation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/stateful-application/basic-stateful-set/#ordered-pod-creation) and when combined with the generally available `readinessProbe` for you pods you could create the desired behaviour. Also the pod name is stable within a `StatefulSet` so your test could then be done with the `hostname` of the `Pod`.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of the accepted answer, wouldn't an [init container](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/) fit your problem description better?

Add some kind of semaphore system (if needed) to ensure it is executed correctly?

Comment: You're right an init container could be an option too for the given example of initializing a database but didn't answer the question on the pod number / order.

Comment: Great idea! (+1'd). I still have use for the StatefulSet, but the init container must provide for some extra functionality I seek. Thx!

Comment: Something new is k8s-AppController from Mirantis - slides, video link at the end: http://www.slideshare.net/PiotrSiwczak/sf-bay-area-kubernetes-meetup-dec8-2016-deployment-models

Comment: 404 Page not found

Comment: Edited answer - https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/